# How to logout on Facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook

I have code for logout on Facebook

```
   var request = WebRequest.Create(LogoutUrl);
   request.GetResponse();
```

My logout url is: `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://188.230.106.25/facebook/Facebook/GetCode&access_token=MY_TOKEN`

But on facebook Debugger this access_token is valid.

How to logout correctly on Facebook using C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next url needs to be on a domain that is registered on the settings page of your app. I don't know if you can use an IP address, but if so, that IP address would need to be plugged in [here](http://developers.facebook.com/apps), otherwise switch to using a domain name instead of IP.

Comment: next url is my Site_URL.  I tried Redirect(LogoutUrl) but the effect is the same.